# Add "delayed close"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, moderation, vote-to-close

Some of our close reasons include a request for additional information, with the implication that this might allow them to reopen. That strikes me as somewhat off-putting to newcomers, so I tend to comment with the request these rather than VTC unless they're pretty close to irredeemable.

It might be kinder to give these a delayed action. "We'll have to close this in a week unless you can clarify/focus" would not have as strong a negative connotation.

Of course making that work would require changes at the SE core level, but I wanted to float a trial balloon before finding out if it was a lead balloon.

Comment: There are a few requests on https://meta.stackexchange.com/ for different variations of this. It probably makes more sense to request this feature over there to apply to all sites rather than just DIY. Personally I'd like a "remind me of this post after $x time" feature to get a notification to revisit the post.

Comment: Probably true. Wanted to check first whether I was completely off in left field.